# Помогите разобраться с кодом, не создаёт записи в колонках

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, sqlite3

```
    #c.execute("CREATE TABLE link (id int, firstlink TEXT(450), secondarylink TEXT(450));")
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('my.sql')
c = conn.cursor()
a  =str(input("Ввод ссылки1: "))
b  =str(input("Ввод ссылки2: "))
n  =int(input("Ввод id: "))
c.execute("INSERT INTO link (firstlink,secondarylink,id) VALUES (?,?,?);",(a,b,n))
conn.commit()
c.execute("SELECT * FROM link;")
print (c.fetchone())
c.close()
```

Весь прикол,в том ,что он показывает только одну запись. Я не могу понять почему так и как вывести всё остальное.

Comment: fetch**one** -> fetch**all**.

Comment: Спасибо большое, забыл совсем про разницу !! )

Comment: У Вас в заголовке вопроса *"не создаёт"*, а в вопросе *"показывает"*. Разные вещи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените `c.fetch`**one**`()` на `c.fetch`**all**`()`.

---

### `fetchone()`

Получает следующую строку из результатов выборки, возвращает одну последовательность значений (столбцов) или `None`, если перебрали все результаты выборки.

### `fetchall()`

Возвращает все (оставшиеся) строки из результатов выборки в виде списка (`list`). Возвращает пустой список, если уже были выбраны все результаты выборки.

---

[fetchone](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchone)
[fetchall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchall)